# How to find the distribution of x-y considering inverse guassian

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let X and Y both be distributed **Inverse Guassian** which are independent, what is the distribution of Z=X−Y? is there any closed form for distribution of Z?!

Comment: Please do not include your email. It is not an accepted practice here. The volunteers will post their answers here itself. Also, show some of your work when you ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are familiar with the basic approach to derive densities of functions of random variables using convolutions (otherwise you should first study it).
The full answer would be rather (too) long, because the algebraic calculations are long and tedious.
So I will leave you to perform the convolution calculations on your own, but I will detail what the convolution will be in this case.

The critical thing is that you examine the difference of two non-negative random variables. Then this difference, $Z$ will range in $(-\infty, \infty)$. These different supports eventually create the need to calculate two different convolutions separately, and results in a piece-wise density.

The distribution function of $Z$ is $P(Z\le z) = P(X-Y \le z)$.
This gives the inequality $x-y \le z \Rightarrow x \le z +y$.
But $X$ is a non-negative random variable. So we must respect $0 \le x \le z +y \Rightarrow 0  \le z +y $.
The random variable $Y$ is also non-negative. So this last inequality will hold for $Z\ge 0$. But for negative values of $Z$ we obtain the restriction $-z \le y$.
So we have to calculate two convolutions:

$$z\le 0:\qquad f_Z(z) = \int_{-z}^{\infty}f_X(z+y)f_Y(y)dy$$
$$z\ge 0:\qquad f_Z(z) = \int_{0}^{\infty}f_X(z+y)f_Y(y)dy$$

Then, a lot of algebra. In the end your density will be piece-wise (but continuous), it will have two branches/functional forms, one for negative values of $Z$, one for positive.